# Rerender map with new values on button click without using state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have been trying to figure out how to rerender the items map with new items when I click the "Mark Read" button. I tried putting the items in a useState and updating the state on button click, but the issue with that is when I set the state it's always one render behind because set state is async. How would I go about implementing this?

```js
const Main: React.FC<MainProps> = (props) => {
  // Get All Feeds
  const feeds = trpc.feed.getAllFeeds.useQuery();

  // Get Items
  let unsorteditems;
  if (props.FeedType == "one") {
    unsorteditems = trpc.feed.getItemsFromFeed.useQuery({
      feedId: props.feedId,
    });
  } else if (props.FeedType == "readalready") {
    unsorteditems = trpc.feed.getReadItems.useQuery();
  } else {
    unsorteditems = trpc.feed.getFeedItemsFromAllFeeds.useQuery();
  }

  // Sort Items than add title, logo, and markedAsRead
  const sorteditems = unsorteditems.data?.sort(
    (objA, objB) => Number(objB.createdAt) - Number(objA.createdAt)
    // Replace in other order to sort in reverse
  );
  let items = sorteditems?.map((item) => {
    const feed = feeds.data?.find((feed) => feed.id == item.feedId);
    return {
      ...item,
      feedTitle: feed?.title,
      feedLogoUrl: feed?.LogoUrl,
      markedAsRead: false,
    };
  });

  const feedName = items?.[0]?.feedTitle;

  // Mark Read function
  const markreadmutation = trpc.feed.markReadUsingUpsert.useMutation();
  const onClickMarkRead = async (itemId: string) => {
    markreadmutation.mutate({ itemId: itemId });
  };

  // I tried this but it didn't work, and I can't use state because its async and dosent update in time
  function updateItems(index: number) {
    const newItems = items?.map((item, i) => {
      if (i == index) {
        return {
          ...item,
          markedAsRead: true,
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    items = newItems;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* I removed alot of code here to make it easier to understand so css may look weird */}
      {/* <!-- Main --> */}
      <div className="basis-5/12 border-l border-slate-300/40">
        <h1 className="sticky top-0 z-50 border-b border-slate-300/40 bg-opacity-60 bg-clip-padding py-2 pl-2 text-xl font-bold backdrop-blur-xl backdrop-filter">
          {props.FeedType == "one"
            ? feedName
            : props.FeedType == "all"
            ? "All Feeds"
            : props.FeedType == "readalready"
            ? "Recently Read"
            : "Woops"}
        </h1>
        <div>
          {items?.length == 0 && <p>No Items</p>}
          {items?.map((item, i) => (
            <div
              className={`border-slate-300/4 relative flex h-28 flex-col border-b ${
                item.markedAsRead ? "bg-gray-200" : "bg-white"
              }`}
              key={item.id}
            >
              {/* ^^^ If item is marked read it will be grayed out ^^^ */}
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  // THIS BUTTON
                  // When I click this is should rerender the map with the item marked as read
                  onClickMarkRead(item.id);
                  updateItems(i);
                }}
              >
                [Mark Read]
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use state. You can't access asynchronous code on first render of React component. And in order to use the latest value of the items, you should store your items in state, then create useCallback function for your async calls and items manipulation (sort etc) and finally call this function in useEffect. It will look something like this:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const getItems = useCallback( async() => {
  const fetchedItems = await yourFetchFunction();
  setItems(fetchedItems);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  getItems();
}, [getItems]);
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying I can't use the useQuery() hook inside a useCallback.

Comment: I think I got this implemented, but it still seems to have the same issue where It's behind, and I have to re-render the component every time for anything to show up.

Comment: Try to add the props that your get function depends on in the useCallback second argument (the array), so it can recall the function and rerender the component on variable change

Comment: I tried that already and doesn't seem to work, it's weird though because it half works now but only certain ones.

Comment: The prop on the callback seems to work but for some reason fetchedItems returns undefined sometimes

Comment: for some reason, useCallback is not getting addeditems correctly

Comment: I tried passing the items into the usecallback, and it works now, but it's an unlimited loop now. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I am shooting in the dark here, because I don't see the updated code, but endless loops in useEffect and useCallbacks are caused by setting state inside them and at the same time observing it for changes by adding the state value in the dependencies array. To avoid this you can update state only if certain condition is met.

Comment: Any idea what kind of condition I can do? Here's a jsfiddle of current code https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=f81kyhdevu

Comment: couldn't open it, are you sure this is the correct link to share?

Comment: I think js fiddle stops sharing when I close the tab, I re-uploaded it GitHub gist: https://gist.github.com/michaelkremenetsky/de615210b7769b0844f7514fee8e1726

Comment: Never mind, I finally figured it out by separating the fetch code into a different file.

Comment: Right, this is always the best decision - exporting the logic into separated component.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the button, you should call the updateItems only after awaiting the mutation. In the current code provided you call it synchronously. You can add it inside onClickMarkRead. Pass the index in it and try like this (in updateItems set items in state after updating them):

```
const onClickMarkRead = async (itemId: string, index: number) => {
  await markreadmutation.mutate({ itemId: itemId });
  updateItems(index);
};
```

If it still doesn't work, you can provide the whole component with the latest code changes via jsFiddle or CodePen or GitHub, so I can see and eventually play around with it.